Python ModuleNotFoundError in venv
I'm working on a Python project involving lane detection, and I've structured my project as shown in the below image.
I'm trying to import a module from lanenet_model in test_lanenet.py using the following code:
python
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/SaiTeja/PycharmProjcts/NewGitCloneSDAI/Lanenet-lane-detection/lanenet_model')
from lanenet_model import lanenet

However, I'm encountering a ModuleNotFoundError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SaiTeja\PycharmProjects\NewGitCloneSDAI\lanenet-lane-detection\tools\test_lanenet.py", line 23, in 
from lanenet_model import lanenet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lanenet_model'
vbnet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lanenet_model'


I've confirmed that __init__.py is present in the lanenet_model directory, making it a package, and I've checked that the path I'm appending to sys.path is correct.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Ensuring the path in sys.path.append() is correct and points to the directory just above lanenet_model.
Checking that __init__.py exists in the lanenet_model directory.
Running the script from a different directory.



always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

in sys.path you have to use path without Lanenet_model - 'C:/Users/SaiTeja/PycharmProjcts/NewGitCloneSDAI/Lanenet-lane-detection. With current sys.path it searchs module Lanenet_model inside folder Lanenet_model - and this is wrong because it has to search module Lanenet_model inside folder Lanenet-lane-detection. With current sys.path you could try to do import lanenet and import lanenet_possprocess without from Lanenet_model

other problem: your folder is lanenet_model with lower case l at the beginning , and file lanenet.py with lower case l so you have to also use from lanenet_model import lanenet with lower case l .

Is there any way to add "import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/SaiTeja/PycharmProjects/NewGitCloneSDAI/Lanenet-lane-detection')" to update entire project? I don't want to add this to every python script in the project

I don't know if you have to add it to all scripts. Maybe you have to add it only to scripts which you start and other file which you import in your script will have it in sys.path. But I never check it. You may also use system variable  PYTHONPATH to add folders - see The initialization of the sys.path module search path — Python documentation
